# Python - \n appearing in concatenated strings

Tags: python, string, concatenation

I've been having an issue with my Python code. I am trying to concatenate the value of two string objects, but when I run the code it keeps printing a '\n' between the two strings.
My code:

```
while i < len(valList):
    curVal = valList[i]
    print(curVal)
    markupConstant = 'markup.txt'
    markupFileName = curVal + markupConstant
    markupFile = open(markupFileName)
```

Now when I run this, it gives me this error:

`OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'cornWhiteTrimmed\nmarkup.txt'`

See that \n between the two strings? I've dissected the code a bit by printing each string individually, and neither one contains a \n on its own. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `curVal` almost definitely ends in a newline. What does `list(curVal)` show?

Comment: When you print a string, a `\n` character is just going to produce a line break.  Try `print(repr(curVal))` to see what's actually there.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is from the code itself (as @Carcigenicate mentioned, `curVal` appears to be the culprit, but as for why I have no idea), but in any kind of string parsing context, `strip()` is your friend to get rid of leading or trailing whitespace.

Comment: You've never shown us `valList`, from which `curVal` is defined.

Comment: Let me guess, you got `varList` by `readlines()` from a file handle? Just `curVal.rstrip()` before concentrating it with your `markupConstant`.

Comment: You are printing the string curVal not the concatenation of curVal and markupConstant.

Comment: The `\n` is a newline character. It probably gets appended automatically when you originally read your `curlVal`. Use the `rstrip()` method on `curlVal` and any other string you read in to remove new lines

Comment: @Magsol Okay, I tried adding the strip() to the string like so:

`markupFileNameStr = markupFileName.strip() `

It still shows the aforementioned error.

@zwer you are absolutely correct, I was just about to post that in response to @Carcigenicate . In the end, adding that rstrip fixed the problem. Thank you all so much for your input, I'm incredibly new to this and I was getting driven up the wall!

Comment: @LSFKing I meant to run `strip()` on `curVal`, not the full `markupFileName`--the newline would be mashed in the middle at that point, and `strip` indeed won't work :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concatenation itself doesn't add the `\n` for sure. `valList` is probably the result of calling `readlines()` on a file object, so each element in it will have a trailing `\n`. Call [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) on each element before using it:

```
while i < len(valList):
    curVal = valList[i].strip()
    print(curVal)
    markupConstant = 'markup.txt'
    markupFileName = curVal + markupConstant
    markupFile = open(markupFileName)
```

Comment: This was the problem, thank you very much. Original credit for an answer goes to @zwer but I can't accept comments as answers, so this will do. 

Note: However, technically, I used rstrip()

Comment: The only difference between `strip` and `rstrip` is that the latter will strip off whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines) *only* on the right end of the string, whereas `strip` will do it on *both* ends of the string. Neither, however, will strip whitespace from somewhere in the middle--hence your earlier comment to me about running it on `markupFileName` and not seeing any change.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are not seeing the \n when you actually print out the python statements is because \n is technically the newline character. You will not see this when you actually print, it will only skip to a new line. The problem is when you have this in the middle of your two strings, it is going to cause problems. The solution to your issue is the strip method. You can read into its documentation here (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_strip.htm) but basically you can use this method to strip the newline character off of any of your strings.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make an addition to the other answers explaining why this came about:

When you need to actually inspect what characters a string contains, you can't simply print it. Many characters are "invisible" when printed.

Turn the string into a list first:

```
list(curVal)
```

Or my personal favorite:

```
[c for c in curVal]
```

These will create lists that properly show all hard to see characters.